# Insert Data into multiple tables in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have five tables and 5 tables are linked.

1) Rules_Group (GroupId-Primary Key) 
2) Rules_Sub_Group (GroupId - Foreign Key from Rules_Group)
3) Rules (SubGroupId - Foreign Key from Rules_Sub_Group)
4) Rules_Expression (RulesId - Foreign Key from Rules)
5) Rules_Expression_Eval (RulesId - Foreign Key from Rules)

How can I write a stored procedure to insert/update records all at a time and if anything fails, I want to roll back the transaction.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What would be the signature of the stored procedure, i.e. its arguments?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I write a stored procedure to insert/update records all at a time and if anything fails, I want to roll back the transaction.

A common way is to establish a `SAVEPOINT` and, if errors occur, `ROLLBACK` to the savepoint.  That gives you the option of continuing the transaction with the next record, if you like.  It also, preserves the transaction to allow you to process a single `COMMIT` only at the very end (which is good for several reasons which may be controversial and weren't the point of your question).

Here is the general idea:

```
FOR r IN ( ... select your source data, or maybe load it from a file ... ) LOOP
BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT myproc_pre_insert;
    INSERT INTO rules_group ...;
    INSERT INTO rules_sub_group ...;
    INSERT INTO rules ...;
    INSERT INTO rules_expression ...;
    INSERT INTO rules_expression_eval ...;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      ROLLBACK TO myproc_pre_insert;
      ... log error, possibly ...
      ... either (A) abort the process ...
      RAISE;
      ... or (B) continue with the next record
      CONTINUE;
END;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
```

Depending on how your tables are and how your source data is, you might also combine some of the five (5) `INSERT` statements, using `INSERT ALL`.